# Can we merge [efi] and [uefi] tags please?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

The UEFI specification is the continuation of the EFI specification (which ceased development in 2005), yet people out of habit frequently refer to UEFI as EFI. Could we merge these two tags please?

Comment: Is there any possibility that someone will be working with the specification as it existed pre-2005?

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous, but it *kind* of looks like some semi-modern Mac hardware still uses non-U EFI (version 1.10, the last).  Maybe.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's possible, but since a lot of people say “EFI” meaning the current version (officially called UEFI), it would be best to use [tag:efi-1] or [tag:efi-1.10] for questions that are specifically about the old versions.

Comment: According to the [Intel EFI homepage](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/unified-extensible-firmware-interface/efi-homepage-general-technology.html), they are the same.  The [tag:efi] would be great if people only used it for pre-2005; but they don't.  [11 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efi+uefi) with both tags; with only 31 questions.  This is more harmful than helpful going forward.